# cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' in home brew installed package but fine in python shell

Tags: python, lxml, pikepdf

I'm trying to run ocrmypdf which was installed via homebrew but am having issues with my local version of lxml (version 4.2.4):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ocrmypdf", line 5, in <module>
    from ocrmypdf.__main__ import run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ocrmypdf/9.8.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ocrmypdf/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import helpers, hocrtransform, leptonica, pdfa, pdfinfo
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ocrmypdf/9.8.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ocrmypdf/pdfa.py", line 38, in <module>
    import pikepdf
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ocrmypdf/9.8.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pikepdf/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .models import (
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ocrmypdf/9.8.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pikepdf/models/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .metadata import PdfMetadata
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ocrmypdf/9.8.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pikepdf/models/metadata.py", line 17, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' ($HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/__init__.py)
```

If I open up a python shell, I'm able to import just fine:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.__file__
'$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-37m-darwin.so'
```

My pythonpath:

```
$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages:$HOME/Code_Repos/invoice2data//src:$HOME/Code_Repos/invoice2data//src/invoice2data:$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages:$HOME/Code_Repos/invoice2data
```

I'm not sure why the homebrewed package is not picking up the module file even though it says it's pointing to the same site-packages folder.

Comment: What happens when you run `from ocrmypdf.__main__ import run` on the shell? A quick hack that might solve your problem is to add the lxml installation path to sys.path before importing ocrmypdf. You'd do it by running `sys.path.append('$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml')`.

Comment: ```>>> import ocrmypdf
>>> ocrmypdf.__file__
>>> print(ocrmypdf.__file__)
None
>>>```

So I can import in a shell no problem, but can't ran't run the executable version from command line.

Comment: Not sure the exact cause, but if i uninstall ocrmypdf via homebrew, and reinstall via pip (as per https://pypi.org/project/ocrmypdf/4.1/) i'm able to get ocrmypdf to work.